# Do we require a keytab entry for all AD users for kerberos based authentication?

Tags: single-sign-on, kerberos, spnego, ntlm-authentication, ntlmv2

I have a web application deployed on jboss. As of now we have implemented NTLMHttpFilter provided by https://www.jcifs.org/. As this java filter supports only NTLMV1, now i need to update my authentication to kerberos based authentication to support kerberos using spnego, but i still not sure, do i have to generate a keytab file for all existing application user. if yes how do i update keytab password every time when user update its windows password? Also Please let me know the keytab location for Service account and user account ?My intention here is providing a promptless sso feature using integrated windows authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need a keytab file for the service account of your application, not for every user. The user requests a service ticket for the application from the KDC.

Comment: Can we use spnego for two different forest? e.g. abc.com and xyz.info ?